# Myself / Me--Which is correct here?

Tags: grammar

I gave everyone at the company, including myself, a huge Christmas bonus.

Is "including myself"—not "including me"—correct here?

Thank you.

Comment: "Including `X`" means _and `X`_. So it's just a conjoined object, and can be switched around: _I gave `X` and everyone at the company_ Which pronoun would you use for _`X`_ here?

Comment: @JohnLawler: "I met three women and a man" = "I met three women including a man"?

Comment: @Brian: In that context, where _everyone at the company_ may or may not include the speaker, it means _and_. It's a clarifying addendum, since the NP is ambiguous. In the example you cite, _three women_ cannot include _a man_; different construction, different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The pronoun *myself* there might be considered either as the object of the present participle *including,* or more likely (see below) as an included component of the object of the finite verb *gave,* i.e., an included component of “everyone at the company.”  But since the person doing the including as well as the giving is you, either way you are at once the subject and the direct object of the verb; and that is precisely the situation where the [reflexive pronoun](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/reflexive-pronouns) *myself* is indeed appropriate.

OED s.v. including *adj.* sense 2:

> *Including* pres. pple. often governs a n. particularizing a person or thing included in a group previously (or afterwards) mentioned; = Inclusive of.

Answer (score 0):

You can go intuitively by the sound of it, instead of figuring it out according to grammatical rules. Thus, you would not say: "I gave me a bonus", therefore, in the sentence in question you should use 'myself".